# How can I render Vue SFC content from API?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vue.js, webpack, server-side-rendering

I have backend API (ASP.NET Core), that get vue pages in SFC format from database. How can I render pages dynamically from this API? Not only template, but all SFC component including  and  sections. I found only part solution with routes.addroutes for routing. But I can't construct component from api.